# Step/Spike detection breakdown for pandas dataframe graph?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am currently trying to learn how to utilize csv data via pandas and matplotlib. I have this issue where for a dataset that clearly has spikes in the data, I would need to "clean up" before evaluating anything out of it. But I am having difficulties understanding how to "detect" spikes in a graph...

So the datatset I am working is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[340.6, 35.66, 33.98, 38.67, 32.99, 32.04, 37.64, 
                            38.22, 37.13, 38.57, 32.4, 34.98, 36.74, 32.9,
                            32.52, 38.83, 33.9, 32.62, 38.93, 32.14, 33.09, 
                            34.25, 34.39, 33.28, 38.13, 36.25, 38.91, 38.9, 
                            36.85, 32.17, -2.07, 34.49, 35.7, 32.54, 37.91, 
                            37.35, 32.05, 38.03, 0.32, 33.87, 33.16, 34.74, 
                            32.47, 33.31, 34.54, 36.6, 36.09, 35.49, 370.51, 
                            37.33, 37.54, 33.32, 35.09, 33.08, 38.3, 34.32, 
                            37.01, 33.63, 36.35, 33.77, 33.74, 36.62, 36.74, 
                            37.76, 35.58, 38.76, 36.57, 37.05, 35.33, 36.41, 
                            35.54, 37.48, 36.22, 36.19, 36.43, 34.31, 34.85, 
                            38.76, 38.52, 38.02, 36.67, 32.51, 321.6, 37.82,
                            34.76, 33.55, 32.85, 32.99, 35.06]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range('2014-03-03 06:00','2014-03-06 22:00',freq='H'))
```

Which produces this graph:

[image: as you can see there are major spikes in this graph]

So all of these values are in the range of 32 to 38. I've intentionally placed very large numbers on indexes of [0, 30, 38, 48, 82] to create spikes in the graph.

Now I was trying to look up how to do this so called "step detection" on a graph, and the only real useful answer I have found is through [this question here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27031/how-to-get-spike-values-from-a-value-sequence), and so utilizing that I have come up with this overall code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[340.6, 35.66, 33.98, 38.67, 32.99, 32.04, 37.64, 
                            38.22, 37.13, 38.57, 32.4, 34.98, 36.74, 32.9,
                            32.52, 38.83, 33.9, 32.62, 38.93, 32.14, 33.09, 
                            34.25, 34.39, 33.28, 38.13, 36.25, 38.91, 38.9, 
                            36.85, 32.17, -2.07, 34.49, 35.7, 32.54, 37.91, 
                            37.35, 32.05, 38.03, 0.32, 33.87, 33.16, 34.74, 
                            32.47, 33.31, 34.54, 36.6, 36.09, 35.49, 370.51, 
                            37.33, 37.54, 33.32, 35.09, 33.08, 38.3, 34.32, 
                            37.01, 33.63, 36.35, 33.77, 33.74, 36.62, 36.74, 
                            37.76, 35.58, 38.76, 36.57, 37.05, 35.33, 36.41, 
                            35.54, 37.48, 36.22, 36.19, 36.43, 34.31, 34.85, 
                            38.76, 38.52, 38.02, 36.67, 32.51, 321.6, 37.82,
                            34.76, 33.55, 32.85, 32.99, 35.06]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range('2014-03-03 06:00','2014-03-06 22:00',freq='H'))
# df.plot()
# plt.show()

threshold = int(len(df['price']) * 0.75)
maxPeaks = argrelextrema(df['price'].values, np.greater, order=threshold)
minPeaks = argrelextrema(df['price'].values, np.less, order=threshold)

df2 = df.copy()
price_column_index = df2.columns.get_loc('price')
allPeaks = maxPeaks + minPeaks
for peakList in allPeaks:
    for peak in peakList:
        print(df2.iloc[peak]['price'])
```

But the issue with this is that it only seems to be returning the indexes of 30 and 82, and its not grabbing the large value in index 0, and also is not grabbing anything in the negative dips. Though I am very sure I am using these methods incorrectly.

Now, I understand for this SPECIFIC issue I COULD just look for values in a column that is either greater or less than a certain value, but I am thinking of situations of dealing with 1000+ entries where dealing with the "lowest/highest normal values" can not accurately be determined, and therefore I just would like a spike detection that works regardless of scale.

So my questions are as follows:

1) The information I've been looking at about step detection seemed really really dense, and very difficult for me to comprehend. Could anyone provide a general rule about how to approaching these "step detection" issues?

2) Are there any public libraries that allows for this kind of work to be done with a little more ease? If so what are they?

3) How can you achieve the same results using vanilla Python? I've been in many workplaces that do not allow for any other libraries to be installed, forcing solutions to be made that does not utilize any of these useful external libraries, so I am wondering if there is some kind of formula/function that could be written to achieve similar results...

4) What other approaches could I use from a Data Analysis standpoint on dealing with this issue? I read something about correlation, standard deviation, but I don't actually know how any of these can be utilized to identify WHERE the spikes are...

EDIT: also, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761712/what-is-a-pythonic-method-to-find-a-step-or-spike-shape-in-a-time-series) as well using scipy's `find_peaks` method, but reading its doc I don't really understand what they represent, and where the values passed came from... Any clarification of this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: well that is interetsing I have just run your data using `find_peaks` and it doesnt find the peak at `df['price'][0]`

Answer (score 3):

Solution using `scipy.signal.find_peaks`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks


df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[340.6, 35.66, 33.98, 38.67, 32.99, 32.04, 37.64, 
                            38.22, 37.13, 38.57, 32.4,  34.98, 36.74, 32.9,
                            32.52, 38.83, 33.9,  32.62, 38.93, 32.14, 33.09, 
                            34.25, 34.39, 33.28, 38.13, 36.25, 38.91, 38.9, 
                            36.85, 32.17, -2.07, 34.49, 35.7, 32.54, 37.91, 
                            37.35, 32.05, 38.03, 0.32,  33.87, 33.16, 34.74, 
                            32.47, 33.31, 34.54, 36.6,  36.09, 35.49, 370.51, 
                            37.33, 37.54, 33.32, 35.09, 33.08, 38.3,  34.32, 
                            37.01, 33.63, 36.35, 33.77, 33.74, 36.62, 36.74, 
                            37.76, 35.58, 38.76, 36.57, 37.05, 35.33, 36.41, 
                            35.54, 37.48, 36.22, 36.19, 36.43, 34.31, 34.85, 
                            38.76, 38.52, 38.02, 36.67, 32.51, 321.6, 37.82,
                            34.76, 33.55, 32.85, 32.99, 35.06]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range('2014-03-03 06:00','2014-03-06 22:00',freq='H'))


x = df['price'].values
x = np.insert(x, 0, 0)              # added padding to catch any initial peaks in data

# for positive peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=50) # hieght is the threshold value
peaks = peaks - 1

print("The indices for peaks in the dataframe: ", peaks)
print(" ")
print("The values extracted from the dataframe")
print(df['price'][peaks])

# for negative peaks
x = x * - 1    
neg_peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0) # hieght is the threshold value
neg_peaks = neg_peaks - 1

print(" ")
print("The indices for negative peaks in the dataframe: ", neg_peaks)
print(" ")
print("The values extracted from the dataframe")
print(df['price'][neg_peaks])
```

First note that the algorithm works in a way that makes comparrisons between values. The upshot being that the first value of the array gets ignored, I suspect that this was the probelm with the solution you posted.

To get around this I padded the `x` array with an extra `0` at position `0` the value you put there is upto you,

`x = np.insert(x, 0, 0)`

The algorthim then returns the *indices* of where the peak values are to be found in the array into the variable `peaks`,

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=50) # hieght is the threshold value
```

As I have added an initial value I have to subtract 1 from each of these indices,

```
peaks = peaks - 1
```

I can now use these indices to extract the peak values from the dataframe,

```
print(df['price'][peaks])
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! the issue with this though is although it resolves the whole initial value issue, it also does not pick up the negative peaks in the graph and only returns the positive peaks. would i then have to come up with another find_peaks line to find these negative peaks? is there no other way to come up with everything (aside from making your own function)?

Comment: OK have added the code for the negative peaks. Its the same proceedure but I just multiplied the array by `-1`

Comment: Hi there, I've taken a look at this solution and although it answers THIS specific case, it does not necessarily answer my initial question of "how do you make it work for all (or most) cases?". and although there was no "direct answer", i am going to take a "yes" to my question of "is it better to make my own function that utilizes find_peaks. I will await perhaps a few more weeks for alternative answers...

Answer (score 0):

In terms of not detecting the peak at the beginning of the data, what you would usually do is re-sample the data set periodically and overlap the start of this sample with the end of the previous sample by a little bit.  This "sliding window" over the data helps you avoid exactly this scenario, missing peaks on the boundary between scans of the data.  The overlap should be greater than whatever your signal detection width is, in the above examples it appears to be a single data point.

For instance, if you are looking at daily data over a period of a month, with a resolution of "1 day," you would start your scan on the last day of the previous month, in order to detect a peak that happened on the first day of this month.